# Pageslide.js and Bootstrap Collapse not working together

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I am trying to add few toggable divs into expandable sliding panel, which is powered by pageslide.js and bootstrap collapse is not working after I put it into that panel. It works great separately though so I believe there is a problem between bootstrap collapse and pageslide.js

I try to use this http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide/ plugin. When I am inserting some panels, the toggle function stops working.

There is a link of my project here: http://ideaformus.lt/clients/kmp5/zemelapio_elementai_paieska.html

Please, you can see the error if you click that arrow in the left side - then you can see three panels with inputs - here they should have a possibility to slide but that toggle function is not working....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did see this message in my developer console when I went to your page.  `console.markTimeline is deprecated. Please use the console.timeStamp instead.` As far as your error have you tried to manually set initiate the collapse?

Something like

```
$('.optioncolumn h3 a').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next('div').collapse('toggle');
});
```

Comment: Worked like a champ! Thank you so much!